# text file altering issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've gotten a text file with a bunch of data on it along with code that outputs a scattergraph, what I need to do is use the variables within the text file to calculate a new variable `a_mag` to replace the given `v_mag` on the graph but I'm stuck on the following lines:

```
for line in lines:
    column = line.split()    
    starID.append(float(column[0]))
    v_mag.append(float(column[1]))
    b_v.append(float(column[2]))
    parallaxes.append(float(column[3]))
    parallax_error.append(float(column[4]))
    d.append(float(1/column[3])) # Distance to star
    a_mag.append(float(column[1]-(5*math.log10(1/column[3]/10))))
```

`d` and `a_mag` are the new variables with d only needed to calculate `a_mag`, the error code is as follows:

```
 22     parallaxes.append(float(column[3]))
 23     parallax_error.append(float(column[4]))
---> 24     float(d.append(1/column[3])) # Distance to star
 25     a_mag.append(float(Column[1]-(5*math.log10(1/Column[3]/10)))) # Absolute V Magnitude
 26 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you add your sample of your input  and desired output ?

Comment: You are trying to divide an `int` and `str`, as the error message says. You need to convert `Column[1]` and `Column[3]` to a `float` first before dividing, as you did above when `append`ing them to the lists

Answer (score -1):

For whatever reason, putting float before every individual 'column[x]' in lines 24 and 25 fixed it.

Comment: d.append(float(1/float(Column[3])))                      
    A_Mag.append(float(float(Column[1])-(5*math.log10(1/float(Column[3])/10))))

Comment: Not "for whatever reason" ! __The reason is quite clear and obvious__: `Column` is a list of strings, so `Colum[x]` is a string (for all valid values of `x`),  so trying to divide an int or float by a string will OF COURSE raise a `TypeError` since dividing a number by a string makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Cillian12421 you don't need to put float everywhere - just convert every column to float, store that somewhere and then use converted value. When you read from file - that all are strings, not numbers. BTW: please use Python convention for naming variables